# Startup Applications App is missing

Tags: apt, server, 19.10, startup-applications

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 and I uninstalled "Startup Applications" without realizing I would need to use it.  I'm now having trouble finding the software.

I've tried running `sudo apt install startup-applications` as well as `apt-get` but I get the message `E: Unable to locate package startup-applications`.

How do I get this application back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close to the real package name.

According to search on https://packages.ubuntu.com you need
to install the [GNOME Startup Applications](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-startup-applications) package:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-startup-applications
```

as [it contains](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/gnome-startup-applications/filelist) needed `gnome-session-properties` executable with needed desktop-file.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that that package is no longer a GNOME package, but an Ubuntu only one (provided via a patch to the `gnome-session` source package).

Answer (score 2):

The package containing the "Startup Applications" utility is "gnome-startup-applications". If you really removed it, you can reinstall it with

```
sudo apt install gnome-startup-applications
```

The name of the executable for the "Startup Application Preferences" tool is `gnome-session-properties`.